# jQuery select elements that match class and attribute?

Tags: jquery

I'm currently selecting all elements with class .follow-container, this is the code:

```
$('.follow-container').html('it's this one');
```

How do I only select elements that have the class and also the attribute `onmousedown="alert()"`

Comment: Just a heads up, you need to escape that apostrophe or use double quotes.

Comment: wow that's a very different question... and an odd way to do things. The content of `onmousedown` is basically a script! o.O

Comment: @radixhound Just checked out your website, spelling mistake! Line 60, "world" not "wold" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to mention but you should really use a [data attribute](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) instead of an unsupported `number`  attribute.

What about `data-number="3"` instead?

You could then select this using:

```
$('.follow-container[data-number="3"]');
```

If you would prefer to use your attribute you could use:

```
$('.follow-container[number="3"]');
```

Comment: Sorry I just wrote number to simplify the question. The attribute was really a long onmousedown.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('.follow-container[number="3"]')
```

Comment: technically this answers the question exactly but the `data-number` solution by [Sam](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1065786/sam)  more helpful and also fully answers the question.

Comment: I just wrote 'number' as attribute to simplify the question. The attribute was really an onmousedown. Anyway I just tried this and works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's the snippet:

```
            $('.follow-container').each(function(idx, ele)
            {
                if($(ele).attr('onmousedown') == 'alert()')
                {
                    // do stuff to $(ele)
                    // $(ele) is the element you want!
                }
            });
```